# High level multipart upload with Boto3 (Python) to AWS Glacier?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

I need to upload a bigger file to AWS Glacier's valut. Because of the size I'm not able to do it in one request so I need to split it to smaller parts and use multipart upload.

Does Boto3 contain a method which takes a big file, splits is and upload it's parts one by one?
As I can see Java client has such method (taken from AWS docs):

> The high-level API provides a method that you can use to upload archives of any size. Depending on the file you are uploading, the method either uploads an archive in a single operation or uses the multipart upload support in Amazon Glacier to upload the archive in parts.

I've tried to use:

```
boto3.client(...).upload_archive(...)
```

but is does not split a file and I get an error.

Is there any other way of doing it without implementing all this low-level stuff (splitting file, sending multiple requests, finishing upload...)?

Comment: Please look for upload_file()/upload_fileobj()  config parameter  that make use of s3transfer config http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig

Comment: @mootmoot I need to send it to AWS Glacier, not to AWS S3.

Comment: The glacier module doesn't use s3 transfer.  You can ask you question/request  here : https://github.com/boto/boto3
Though you may use S3 as work around. i.e  use s3 upload, and set the lifecycle transit to Glacier in 1 day.

Comment: @mootmoot Yes, I know it doesn't. That is my point. I'm not interested in S3 here... even as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.upload_multipart_part

I'll add some relevant info from the docs.

**upload_multipart_part(**kwargs)**

> This operation uploads a part of an archive. You can upload archive parts in any order. You can also upload them in parallel. You can upload up to 10,000 parts for a multipart upload.
>
> Amazon Glacier rejects your upload part request if any of the
>   following conditions is true:
>
> - SHA256 tree hash does not match To ensure that part data is not
>     corrupted in transmission, you compute a SHA256 tree hash of the part
>     and include it in your request. Upon receiving the part data, Amazon
>     Glacier also computes a SHA256 tree hash. If these hash values don't
>     match, the operation fails.
> - Part size does not match The size
>     of each part except the last must match the size specified in the
>     corresponding InitiateMultipartUpload request. The size of the last
>     part must be the same size as, or smaller than, the specified size.
> - Range does not align The byte range value in the request does not
>     align with the part size specified in the corresponding initiate
>     request. For example, if you specify a part size of 4194304 bytes (4
>     MB), then 0 to 4194303 bytes (4 MB - 1) and 4194304 (4 MB) to 8388607
>     (8 MB - 1) are valid part ranges. However, if you set a range value of
>     2 MB to 6 MB, the range does not align with the part size and the
>     upload will fail.

Here is the request syntx

```
response = client.upload_multipart_part(
vaultName='string',
uploadId='string',
range='string',
body=b'bytes'|file
```

)

And the parameter descriptions

**accountId** (string)

The AccountId value is the AWS account ID of the account that owns the vault. You can either specify an AWS account ID or optionally a single '- ' (hyphen), in which case Amazon Glacier uses the AWS account ID associated with the credentials used to sign the request. If you use an account ID, do not include any hyphens ('-') in the ID.

**vaultName** (string)
[REQUIRED]

The name of the vault.

**uploadId** (string)
[REQUIRED]

The upload ID of the multipart upload.

**checksum** (string)

The SHA256 tree hash of the data being uploaded.

**range** (string)

Identifies the range of bytes in the assembled archive that will be uploaded in this part. Amazon Glacier uses this information to assemble the archive in the proper sequence. The format of this header follows RFC 2616. An example header is Content-Range:bytes 0-4194303/*.

**body** (bytes or seekable file-like object)

The data to upload.

Comment: Consider adding information here rather than just a link. If the web address changes, that will keep the question useful.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is here:
https://github.com/tbumi/glacier-upload/blob/develop/main.py

```
response = glacier.complete_multipart_upload(
    vaultName=vault_name, uploadId=upload_id,
    archiveSize=str(file_size), checksum=total_tree_hash)
```

The above does the job you are looking for.